# Prove the inequality $p_{n+1}<{2^{2^n}}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Problem:** Let $p_n$ be the nth prime. Prove that 
$$p_{n+1}<{2^{2^n}}$$

Hint: note that $p_1 \cdot p_2\cdot ...\cdot p_n +1 \geq p_{n+1}$

I'm stuck in this problem , I don't even know how to prove the hint.

Answer (score 1):

For the hint, you know that $p_1 p_2 \cdots p_n + 1$ has at least one prime divisor and you can check that none of $p_1, \ldots, p_n$ fit.

As for the main question, I suggest induction.